# Echoing data if it exists

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display default data if the table is empty. I searched in the laravel documentation and found [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data).

In my controller i send data to my `show.blade.php`

```
public function show($id)
{
    //Get profile data from the user
    $user = User::find($id);        

    return view( 'gebruiker/show',[
        'user' => $user,
    ] );
}
```

And in my `blade` I display the data

```
@foreach ($user->profile as $profile)

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" align="center"> 
        <h1>{{ $profile->user->name or 'Geen naam' }}
        </h1>
        <h3>{{ $profile->age or 'Geen leeftijd' }}</h3>
        <span>{{ $profile->country or 'Geen land' }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 follow line" align="center">
        <h3>
             Bezoekers <br/> <span>{{ $profile->visitors or 'Geen bezoekers' }}</span>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 login_control text-center">
            <br>
            {{ $profile->profile or 'Geen beschrijving' }}

    </div>
@endforeach
```

When `$profile->age` is not empty it shows data but when there is no data it just shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing in my row. When I vardump `$user->profile` `age` it is empty.

Comment: ....... empty?? show a dump.

Comment: `["age"]=>
        string(0) ""`

Comment: I have no idea how you get "nothing". http://ideone.com/gpOw12

Comment: Why not? There is nothing in my database so what should it return then?

Comment: sigh. in the output.

Answer (score 1):

In blade "or" checks only if variable exists.
Lest try something like that:

```
@if(!empty($profile->age))
   {{ $profile->age }}
@else
  Geen leeftijd
@endif
```

Comment: Yep this works.. so this is not possible with or? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
@if($profile->age !='' && $profile->age !='0')
{{ $profile->age }}
@else
Geen leeftijd
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can create an accessor in your model:

```
public function getAgeAttribute($value)
{
    return !empty($value) ? $value : 'Geen leeftijd';
}
```

Ideally this should live in a presenter. Too bad `{{ $profile->age or 'Geen leeftijd' }}` doesn't work, it should. Probably someone will do a PR for it soon enough.